# Trouble getting Javascript Promise result

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

My "save" function asynchronously invokes my "uploadPart" function. "uploadPart" should save the part it is given, then return the generated part id.  Within "uploadPart", I'm able to write the part id to the console - it is correct.

However, the "save" method's "then" always receives "undefined".

Here's the code I'm using.

```
async uploadPart(part: any): Promise<string> {            
                        
    const apiUrl = `${this.root}/api/Part/Upload`;

    // Saves the part and returns the generated part id.
    var partResult = await fetch(apiUrl,
        {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: "include",
            mode: "same-origin",
            body: part
        })
        .then((response) => {
            // get the generated part id - it's a string
            return response.text();
        });

    console.log("generated part id is " + partResult);

    return partResult;
},

async save(): Promise<string> {
            
    try {
        await this.validate()
            .then(await this.uploadPart(this.chosenFile), this.validationBad)
            .then((promise: Promise<String>) => {
                // Here, "promise" only shows "undefined"
                console.log("in try, part id is " + promise);
                return promise;
            });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("in the catch!");
    }
    return;            
},

async validationBad(): Promise<string> {
    return Promise.reject();
},
```

Comment: Your `save()` function returns nothing.

Comment: also you did not post the `validate()` for some reason, and that's probably the most interesting part of the problem.

Comment: The result of `await this.uploadPart(this.chosenFile)`, is not a promise.  Try removing the `await`.

Comment: `.then()` takes a callback *function*, not a promise (or the result of the `await`). Having to type `then((promise: Promise<String>) => {` in the next call hints at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's returning undefined because you're mixing async/await and promise chaining methods. The old way to handle promises was to call your promise and then chain the methods with `.then` for example: `fetch(url).then(do something)`

With `async/await`, you set your function to be asynchronous and then await for the data to be returned. So in your case

```js
async save(): Promise<string> {
            
    try {
        await this.validate();
        const uploadPromise = await this.uploadPart(this.chosenFile), this.validationBad);
        console.log("in try, part id is " + uploadPromise);
        return uploadPromise;

    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("in the catch!");
    }
    return;            
},
```

note this similar pattern can be applied to your upload function as well. Checkout the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/promise-chaining-is-dead-long-live-async-await-445897870abc/) for a deeper dive

Answer (score 0):

A coworker found the issue.

This...

```
.then(await this.uploadPart(this.chosenFile), this.validationBad)
```

...should have been this...

```
.then(() => this.uploadPart(this.chosenFile), this.validationBad)
```

My incorrect way caused "this.uploadPart" to be evaluated outside the promise.

Thanks everyone for your feedback.